# Getting Error MismatchSenderId gcm php

Tags: php, google-cloud-messaging

When i am sending message from the php application. It's showing the below error :

```
{"multicast_id":4689507259280367300,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"MismatchSenderId"}]}
```

I have tried with serverkey, browserkey and android key.

Am i missing anything on the android applicaiton side? I am sending the device id to server and saving the generated regid(got from gcm) to text file on server.

What am i missing ? Any Idea?

Comment: Have you tried looking into the docs from google?

Comment: you mean following the google guide? Yes i did that. I am not sure if i am making mistake on the application side while registering with the gcm

Answer (score 0):

You usually get this error if you're not using the appropriate sender ID.

The [error codes](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes) for the HTTP Connection Server references discusses the error.

> Mismatched Sender | 200 + error:MismatchSenderId  | A registration token is tied to a certain group of senders. When a client app registers for GCM, it must specify which senders are allowed to send messages. You should use one of those sender IDs when sending messages to the client app. If you switch to a different sender, the existing registration tokens won't work.

Ensure that the sender ID used to send the message is correct.